# I got "scheme application not a procedure" in the last recursive calling of a function

Tags: recursion, if-statement, scheme, racket

so here is the code:

```
(define (time-prime-test n)
  (newline)
  (display n)
  (start-prime-test n (runtime)))

(define (start-prime-test n start-time)
  (if (prime? n)
      (report-prime (- (runtime) start-time))))

(define (report-prime elapsed-time)
  (display " *** ")
  (display elapsed-time))

(define (search-for-primes n m)
  (if (< n m) 
      ((time-prime-test n)
       (search-for-primes (+ n 1) m))
      (display " calculating stopped. ")))
(search-for-primes 100000 100020)
```

and i got this error after "calculating stopped." has been displayed. like below:

> 100017 
>   100018 
>   100019 *** 54 calculating stopped. . . application: not a procedure;  expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
>   given: #<void>
>   arguments...:
>    #<void>

Comment: Note: if you run this in DrRacket, the IDE's error highlight should be surrounding the function application that's causing the issue.  Do you see this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You intend to execute two expressions inside the consequent part of the `if`, but `if` only allows one expression in the consequent and one in the alternative.

Surrounding both expressions between parenthesis (as you did) won't work: the resulting expression will be evaluated as a function application of the first expression with the second expression as its argument, producing the error `"application: not a procedure; expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments ..."`, because `(time-prime-test n)` does not evaluate to a procedure, it evaluates to `#<void>`.

You can fix the problem by either using a `cond`:

```
(define (search-for-primes n m)
  (cond ((< n m)
         (time-prime-test n)
         (search-for-primes (+ n 1) m))
        (else
         (display " calculating stopped. "))))
```

Or a `begin`:

```
(define (search-for-primes n m)
  (if (< n m)
      (begin
        (time-prime-test n)
        (search-for-primes (+ n 1) m))
      (display " calculating stopped. ")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! Can't verify it now since i'm at work, I think you're absolutely right about this.

Answer (score 3):

```
  ((time-prime-test n)
   (search-for-primes (+ n 1) m))
```

This will try to apply the result of `time-prime-test` as a procedure. `time-prime-test` doesn't return a procedure. Use `begin`:

```
  (begin
   (time-prime-test n)
   (search-for-primes (+ n 1) m))
```